# jQuery's html function breaks value with html special characters?

Tags: jquery

I have a div that must generate ***dynamic*** input text:

```
  var hh = "<input type='text' value='{0}' />";
//hh=hh.replace("{0}",list[2].w); from ajax
   hh=hh.replace("{0}","i don't know");

$("#div1").html(hh);
```

When i set text to div, the input value is : i don

('t know) is removed.

https://jsfiddle.net/fpqggc0f/4/

Comment: Well, if we want to be precise, _you_ broke the HTML syntax, before you even passed it to `.html()` ... And in spite of all answers so far that only fix the issue by correcting the quotes for the specific example, you rather need to go read up on what context-aware escaping means. If this value is user input or comes from somewhere else - then it needs to be treated properly _before_ you introduce it into the HTML context in the first place. (And then that HTML needs to be treated properly, before it gets put into the JS context.)

Comment: Excuse me, i edit my post.

Comment: If you get the value via AJAX, meaning you have it in a variable at this point already - then the easiest way to handle this properly would be to generate the input element from a string without the value first, and then use `.val()` to set the value afterwards. (Use `.attr` to set `defaultValue`, too, if the functionality that implies is required.)

Comment: But hh is a huge html

Comment: How does that change anything? Use it right as it is, and create elements from it using `.html()` ... then all you have to do afterwards is to select the input element that has the value `{0}` (or them, should that placeholder occur multiple times), which you can easily do using the attribute selector, and then you set the value using `.val() `

Comment: How can i do this (.val()) for :  https://jsfiddle.net/fpqggc0f/4/

Comment: Well plain and simple, as I said ... https://jsfiddle.net/fpqggc0f/5/

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 2):

You have the same quote inside the value attribute, as the quotes surrounding it.

You could use doublequotes and escape them

```
$("#div1").html("<input type=\"text\" value=\"i don't know\" />");
```

Or create the element with jQuery

```
var input = $('<input />', {
                type  : "text",
                value : "i don't know"
});

$('#div1').html(input);
```

Comment: This answer still applies, and you shouldn't change questions to something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this:

```
$("#div1").html("<input type='text' value='i don&#39;t know' />");
```

where `&#39;` is HTML entity for showing `'`.

For more, you can take a look at [Character entity references in HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML).

Answer (score 0):

Simply this should work. Just add a backslash in don't.

```
$("#div1").html("<input type='text' value='i don\'t know' />");
```